# PowerApps sharing

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have a user who has shared multiple apps connected with a SharePoint list but is unable to do so for PowerApps. She gets the error "Sorry there was a problem loading the data" and "Share" button gets greyed out.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this user an owner/co-owner of the App? Users have to be an owner/co-owner of the App in order to share the App.

And you could try to export the App and import it as a new app then delete the previous app and rename the new one the same.

For Reference: [PowerApps - New Share Dialog not working](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-New-Share-Dialog-not-working/td-p/180873)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Casey. Yes, the user is the owner of the app and she wants to share it with a co-owner.